# Link down on Intel ethernet port

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, intel

Some basic diagnostics + config:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"

$ uname -a
Linux myhost 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)

$ dmesg
[    2.044198] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:26:2d:f2:a2:0c
[    2.044200] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.044318] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 9, PHY: 10, PBA No: A002FF-0FF
[    2.045476] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[   38.880455] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   39.076311] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/enp0s25
[connection]
id=enp0s25
uuid=444edb78-3e4f-4e97-a4cd-bf6970ba67b8
type=ethernet
interface-name=enp0s25
permissions=
timestamp=1518274444

[ethernet]
auto-negotiate=true
mac-address=00:26:2D:F2:A2:0C
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-priority=100
dns-search=
may-fail=false
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-priority=100
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto

$ ethtool enp0s25
Settings for enp0s25:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: no
```

Since this is the same cable I was using two days ago, I fear the hardware itself has gone bad. In addition, I have ruled out the cable and switchport by observing them work correctly with a different PC. Is there anything else that could cause this?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the output of `ethtool enp0s25`.

Comment: It shows link not detected. Intel cards tend to be very well supported. Try with a different cable, and verify with a different PC that you indeed have link on that cable. If that fails, then it's hardware.